# Changing Component React Web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to react and I want to know how to change page clicking on a link / button, I've tried this npm package: [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

The problem is that when I click on the link , the path in the url entry change but the page remains the same, here is landing page code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import global from "../resource/global.json";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

<div className="row" style={{ margin: "auto" }}>
            <div className="row float-left" style={{ margin: "auto" }}>
              <Router>
                <Link
                  to={""}
                  style={{
                    marginRight: "15px",
                    border: "none",
                    color: global.GUI.GRIGIOSCURO,
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    display: "inline-block"
                  }}
                >
                  Home
                </Link>
                <Link
                  to={"/terms"}
                  style={{
                    marginRight: "15px",
                    border: "none",
                    color: global.GUI.GRIGIOSCURO,
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    display: "inline-block"
                  }}
                >
                  Termini e Condizioni
                </Link>

                <Link
                  to={"/terms"}
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    marginRight: "15px",
                    border: "none",
                    color: global.GUI.GRIGIOSCURO,
                    textAlign: "center",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    display: "inline-block"
                  }}
                >
                  Privacy
                </Link>
              </Router>
            </div>
```

And here is my project directory:

```
public
|_icon.ico
|_index.html
|_manifest.json
|_src
   |_component 
      |_landing.jsx
      |_login.jsx
      |_terms.jsx
```

I just want to go from landing to terms clicking on the link button, any suggestions? Am I doing something wrong? thanks

Comment: You'll need to render some routes. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

Comment: Hello NIcholas, thanks for your answer , can you please be more specific ? Can you please provide a piece of code with an example path or structure ? I've followed the quick start section here : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start  and there is no mention of routing rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component that react-router use for changing your page based on url is `<Route>`. In your example code you have none of those, so your page will never change. Routes let you specify that when the url matches a certain pattern, you want a certain component to be rendered.

For example, in the quick start section ([found here](http://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)) there is this mention of route rendering

```
{/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
  renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
<Switch>
  <Route path="/about">
    <About />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/users">
    <Users />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

That code will render the `<About/>` component if the url matches `"/about"`, the `<Users/>` component if the url matches `"/users"`, and the `<Home/>` component otherwise.

Comment: It was all a bit confusing: basically you don't need to load you main component in App.js (or index.js whatever), you just need to render this code and the routing will automatically render the correct page(component) based on the url. Thank you so much !